# How is a Rising Edge defined on STM32?

Tags: stm32, gpio-external-interrupt

I'm playing with an STM32F0 and the datasheet clearly defines what a HIGH and LOW signal level is, but I can't find a definition for a Rising Edge. Is it required to go from "LOW" to "HIGH"? I assume that there is some delta/travel in voltage required before it's considered a rising edge? And where in the datasheet (or user man) can I find this? I just want to know what my input (EXTI) should be able to deliver to trigger the MCU, and what won't trigger the STM... ~ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A "rising edge" is the transition of a signal from a Low level to a High level - the signal rises.

A "falling edge" occurs when a signal changes from a High level to a Low level - the signal falls down.

Comment: @ Peter Bennet - So, if I power my STM with 3V3 and LOW is defined as max 0.3*VDDIO (so, ~1V) and HIGH is 0.7*VDDIO (~2.3V), then when my signal is HIGH, a next Rising Edge will only be detected when it drops first to below 1V and rises again to at least 2.3V, correct? (This, assuming it of course happens fast enough @DKNguyen). I mean, dropping till 1.5V and then rising to 3V won't count, right?

Comment: Rising or falling edge terms imply a digital signal that will be at either a legal Low or legal High value.  In your example, 1.5 V is not a legal vlaue - there is no guarantee what logic level that voltage will be interpreted as, so we can't say if the signal dropping to 1.5 volts will be seen as a transition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a very very slow edge transition, then that will cause problems for your MCU, as well as most other digital inputs since the grey zone between HI an LO is undefined and will cause metastability or other issues. Run it through a comparator with hysteresis or one that can handle slowly changing inputs if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

1. The GPIO pins when configured as interrupt inputs, will have a Schmidt trigger circuit enabled at the input ports (STM32L4xx family, for example).
2. A rising edge detection may happen or may not happen when you drop to just 1.5 V and then go back to 3.3 V. **You have to adhere to the datasheet recommendation** in order to have reliable performance.
3. The signal can be either read as logic -0 or read as logic-1 when the signal is at 1.5 V.
4. The problem of spikes must be solved by proper terminations.